# Настройка TabLayout и TabItem(перенос строки)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-tablayout

Столкнулся с проблемой переноса строки в TabLayout, или если быть точнее TabItem. Рисунок прилагается. Необходимо чтобы "Обратная связь" и "Личный кабинет" писались в две строки. Как это сделать?

[image: Рисунок1]

tab_layout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
             <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                 android:id="@+id/tablayout_menu_deal"
                 android:text="@string/menu_deal"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_deal"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
             <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                 android:id="@+id/tablayout2"
                 android:text="@string/menu_request"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_request"
                 android:ems="10"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
             <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                 android:id="@+id/tablayout_menu_profile"
                 android:text="@string/menu_profile"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
             <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                 android:id="@+id/tablayout_menu_feedback"
                 android:text="@string/menu_feedback"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

style.xml

```
  <style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">7sp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">1sp</item>
        <item name="android:minLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">100</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном примере TabLayout настраивался под активность. При переходе на фрагменты, перенос осуществляется автоматически.